# What are the recommended replacement for deprecated LaTeX3 macros?

Tags: latex3

I found `file_get_full_name` for `file_add_path`; but there are many deprecated removed. Is there a list for all and their recommended replacement?

Comment: There is a list of removed commands in [the changelog](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/7d90c3a0ae0c1656916e0cb33a070d005fb93700/l3kernel/CHANGELOG.md#removed-2) but it's not very accessible and often times commands are removed without replacements, e.g. all the `\toks_` commands.

Comment: @HenriMenke Removals without replacements are not that common and usually for things that don't need/warrant one. (The `toks` functions wen years ago and were replaced by `tl` operations, for example.) I'm not sure why you say the ChangeLog is  not accessible: it's on GitHub and publicly-visible.

Comment: @JosephWright With not accessible I meant that it is not in the form of a list of removed commands with their corresponding replacements.  The reader definitely has to invest some effort to find what they are looking for.

Comment: @HenriMenke ah rihgt: we have a list of removals (`l3obsolete`), but replacements are not always simple 'drop ins' so it's harder.

Answer (score 3):

Since the start of 2018 we have had a (reasonably) detailed [changelog](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/l3kernel/CHANGELOG.md) for `expl3` which has entries like

```
### Deprecated
- `\token_get_prefix_spec:N`, `\token_get_arg_spec:N`,
  `\token_get_replacement_spec:N` replaced by `\cs_prefix_spec:N`,
  `\cs_argument_spec:N`, `\cs_replacement_spec:N`, respectively
```

Older deprecations (as for the one you mention) will not be present, though you can always try using the macro and reading what error it raises.